# How to disable toggling with flex buttonbar

Tags: apache-flex, toggle, flex-spark, buttonbar

How to disable the toggle nature of buttons in spark:Buttonbar so that it would behave similar to mx:ButtonBar?

Answer (score 4):

This works on the button bar:

```
requireSelection="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make a visual change:

Create a custom skin class so that the "[down state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#SkinState%3adown)" of the button uses the same skin as the '[up state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#SkinState%3aup)'.

Comment: Yep, Flex 4 Spark components are built for ease of skinning / design; and with such changes some things are harder.